# Problema con excepciones en una plantilla de clase (C++)

Tags: c++, excepciones, names

## Introducción:

Buenas a todos, estoy haciendo una práctica de la universidad en la que tenemos un documento que contiene las palabras que no existen en el diccionario en una lista enlazada hecha por nosotros mismos.

Muy bien, yo he creado una lista enlazada y la he probado, funciona sin problemas.

### ¿Qué ocurre?

Al añadir mediante una composición la lista enlazada como atributo de la clase documento me aparecen errores que no tenía antes relaciones que la excepciones de la clase ListaEnlazada. Estos errores me señalan que las funciones de excepción no son plantillas de clase, y no entiendo porque sucede esto ya que antes la Lista enlazada me funcionaba perfectamente y solo me aparecen los errores al añadirla como atributo a Documento.

#### LISTA ENLAZADA:

no puedo mostrar todo el código por si lo encuentra otro alumno y me lo copia, entonces me saltaría el anticopy y estaría suspenso :(
Pero en esa excepción es una de todas las que falla.

```
template<class T>
bool ListaEnlazada<T>::estaOrdenado()
{
    if(cabecera!=0 && cola!=0)
    {
    Nodo<T>*p=cabecera;
    while (p!=cola) {
        bool comparacion=*p>*p->sig;
            if(comparacion)//el fallo está aquí
            {
                return false;
            }
            p = p->sig;

    }
    return true;
    }else
    {
        throw range_error("ListaEnlazada::estaOrdenado:: La lista esta vacia");
    }
    
}
```

#### CLASE DOCUMENTO:

```
#ifndef DOCUMENTO_H
#define DOCUMENTO_H
#include "ListaEnlazada.h"  
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Palabra.h"

class Documento {
public:
    Documento();
    Documento(std::string nombre)
    {
        this->nombreFich=nombre;
    }
    Documento(const Documento& orig);
    virtual ~Documento();
    void addInexitente(Palabra &p)
    {
       palabrasInexistentes.insertarFinal(p);
    }
private:
    std::string nombreFich="";
    ListaEnlazada<Palabra> palabrasInexistentes;

};

#endif /* DOCUMENTO_H */
```

#### ERRORES DE COMPILACIÓN:

```
cd 'C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VectorDinamico'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/vectordinamico.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Documento.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Documento.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Documento.o Documento.cpp
In file included from Documento.h:16,
                 from Documento.cpp:14:
ListaEnlazada.h: In member function 'bool ListaEnlazada<T>::insertaOrdenado(const T&)':
ListaEnlazada.h:76:14: error: 'range_error' does not name a type
   76 |     } catch (range_error &a) {
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~
ListaEnlazada.h:78:16: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
   78 |         msg += a.what();
      |                ^
ListaEnlazada.h:79:15: error: there are no arguments to 'range_error' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'range_error' must be available [-fpermissive]
   79 |         throw range_error(msg);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~
ListaEnlazada.h:79:15: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
ListaEnlazada.h: In member function 'bool ListaEnlazada<T>::estaOrdenado()':
ListaEnlazada.h:124:15: error: there are no arguments to 'range_error' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'range_error' must be available [-fpermissive]
  124 |         throw range_error("ListaEnlazada::estaOrdenado:: La lista esta vacia");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~
ListaEnlazada.h: In member function 'void ListaEnlazada<T>::borra(Iterador<T>&)':
ListaEnlazada.h:152:15: error: there are no arguments to 'invalid_argument' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'invalid_argument' must be available [-fpermissive]
  152 |         throw invalid_argument("ListaEnlazada::borra::El iterador no es valido");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ListaEnlazada.h: In member function 'void ListaEnlazada<T>::insertar(Iterador<T>&, const T&)':
ListaEnlazada.h:176:15: error: there are no arguments to 'invalid_argument' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'invalid_argument' must be available [-fpermissive]
  176 |         throw invalid_argument("ListaEnlazada::insertar::El iterador no es valido");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ListaEnlazada.h: In member function 'T& ListaEnlazada<T>::inicio()':
ListaEnlazada.h:265:15: error: there are no arguments to 'invalid_argument' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'invalid_argument' must be available [-fpermissive]
  265 |         throw invalid_argument("ListaEnlazada::inicio::no hay elementos en la lista");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ListaEnlazada.h: In member function 'T& ListaEnlazada<T>::final()':
ListaEnlazada.h:280:15: error: there are no arguments to 'invalid_argument' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'invalid_argument' must be available [-fpermissive]
  280 |         throw invalid_argument("ListaEnlazada::borrar::no hay elementos en la lista");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Documento.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Adrian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VectorDinamico'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: Tienes que entender que no es posible dar una respuesta **sin ver el código**. Tienes mensajes de error de líneas que no muestras. Tampoco es necesario que lo muestres todo. Intenta generar un [mcve], y durante el proceso puede que te des cuenta tu mismo de los errores.

Comment: El único error que si muestras ... ¿ Has incluido la cabecra `<stdexcept>` ? ¿ Tienes hecho `using namespace std;` ? Porque, el nombre completamente cualificado de la clase es `std::range_error`.

Comment: he probado el using namespace std; y me funciona con eso, nose muy bien porque, pero ha funcionado.

Comment: Ha funcionado porque `range_error` es una clase que está incluida dentro de este espacio de nombres, luego o usas `catch( std::range_error /* ... */)` o `using namespace std;`. El resto de errores derivan de este primero, ya que el compilador no conoce `range_error`, luego no puede _crear_ la variable `a`, como no la puede crear no puedes llamar a `what` ... y así